# Format Date Error

Tags: vba, date, time, format

I'm trying to place adate and time in a newly created sheet name:

```
 Sub errorlist()
    Sheets.Add.Name = "errorsheet" & Format(Now, "dd_mm_yyyy ss_nn_hh")
 End Sub
```

But vba gives me a message saying

```
  "compile error:
   wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"
```

What can be the problem here? Any ideas.

The code is a part of a 300 line code which i cant mention here but im sure it has no impact on the format function.

Comment: works fine for me. Are you sure you get an error exact in this line?

Comment: @simoco yes im sure, it's th format funtion thats highlighted in yellow

Comment: can you try to evaluate the code I've posted as answer? without other 300 lines of code... Will you get an error? And in what line?

Comment: Yes Im getting the same exact error

Comment: In what line? in `wb.Name =...`?

Comment: Try to add sheet with name `errorsheet21_01_2014 46_32_22` manually (without VBA)

Comment: it works fine i can rename a the sheet manually

Comment: can i avoid the format function somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use following code:

```
Sub errorlist()
    Dim wb As Worksheet

    Set wb = Sheets.Add
    wb.Name = "errorsheet" & Format(Now, "dd_mm_yyyy ss_nn_hh")

End Sub
```

P.S. as follows from comments, OP has defined his own procedure, called `Format` and there was a reason why an error triggered. So, `Format(Now, "dd_mm_yyyy ss_nn_hh")` can be replaced with `Replace(CStr(Now), "-", "_")` or sth like this.

Comment: try to add `MsgBox "errorsheet" & Format(Now, "dd_mm_yyyy ss_nn_hh")` in the first line of `sub`. What would you get?

Comment: the word format in this line is highlighted with and the same message appears

Comment: what is your default date format? what you get in line `MsgBox Now`?

Comment: it says:"error 1004 unable to get the text property in the worksheetfnction class"

Comment: what about this code: `wb.Name = "errorsheet" & Replace(CStr(Now), "-", "_")`?

Comment: its saying that im tying an invalid sheet name, its why im formating time in the first place if i could just get it into a valid format without using the format function.

Comment: have you got **your own** procedure called `Format`?

Comment: it's ok:) no problems)